# I want to list all database,respective all tables using ms.sqlserver.server.dll in c# code?

Tags: c#, sql-server

How to get into ms SQL Server using microsoft_sqlserver_server namespace using C# code? I want to list all databases, respective tables using that namespace.

Comment: What code have you tried to use?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It's very nice that you've told us what you want. What have you tried so far to do it that isn't working? We're not a code writing service where you post what you want to do and someone writes the code for you. We're here to try and help, but you need to try to do it yourself first. Have you at least tried searching first? (Please read the [SO question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/172661) - if the post is too long, read the first answer to it.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `SmoApplication Class`

```
DataTable servers = SmoApplication.EnumAvailableSqlServers(true);

foreach (DataRow server in servers.Rows)
{
    Console.WriteLine(server[Name] + " " + server[Server]);
    foreach(Database database in server.Databases){
        Console.WriteLine(database.Name);
        foreach (Table tb in database.Tables) {
            Console.WriteLine(tb.Name);
       }
    }
}
```